# Contract not properly deployed with Remix

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, bsc

Can someone help me deploy a token contract with Remix?

I try to deploy [this contract](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YumYumFarm/YumYumFarm/main/SC) using [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) and [this is the result](https://bscscan.com/address/0x85de49d220baca2f60c37f770b88352709b291a5).

The contract deployed does not appear to be my token contract.

How can I deploy my token contract with Remix?

Comment: Welcome! We ask posters to please post their code and errors in the question instead of in links. It makes it much easier for users to see the question in its entirety and to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not deploy the right contract on remix. Just before clicking on deploy, you have to select your contract, which I believe is named YumYumFarm, in the drop-down menu (see screenshot where Storage is).

[image: Remix deploy]